# difficulties facing with multiple selection in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview` which has multiple selections.  In each item, there is a `textview` saying "MORE".  On clicking on the textview, it shows the details of the product on the next page.

I have done this in listview's onitemclicklistener `pr_id = tx.getText().toString();` where `tx` is a text view in list having product id and `pr_id` is the product id which I am sending to the next page through an intent.`

```
more.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent i1 = new Intent(Product_List.this,
                            Product_View.class);
                    i1.putExtra("productid", pr_id);

                    Log.i("pid", pr_id);

                    startActivity(i1);

                }
            });`
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is that since I have multiselection and say user has selected 3 items from `listview` in order of 1st, 2nd and 3rd, then when they click on 1st item's "MORE" button.

Clicking the 'MORE' button should show the details of the 1st item. But, since they have selected the 3rd item in their list, these details are shown instead, meaning that the last selected item holds the view instead of the selected 1st item.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: you have to use check box for that or set a property multiple choice to your listview

Comment: i have set multichoce but in my design i dont have checkbox..so any how i have to go by this design..

Comment: you have to make custom layout with check box for listview

Comment: sorry i didnt get you..the project which i m making does not have any checkbox..so how can i add check box..

Comment: you can use 1) http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html  2) http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/11/implement-custom-multi-select-listview.html

Answer (score 0):

In your `ListViewAdapter` when creating view for a list item, use `setTag()` on the "more"-TextView to add its `pr_id` to it. In `more`'s listener call `getTag()` to retrieve the right id.

Comment: @user2595325 The links mentioned by Shani Goriwal show how to create a custom `ArrayAdapter`. In its `getView()` you can set the tag